# Unable to generate avro generic record from object

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I am trying to send avro records to A Kafka topic using Kafka producer. I have a User class and I am sending object of that class. Below code works fine if i use `avroRecord.put();` to set each attribute. But what i want is to create A Generic Record from an object without using avroRecord.put(); for each and every attribute.

User class

```
public class User {
    int id;

    String name;

    public User(int id, String name) {

        super();

        this.id = id;

        this.name = name;

    }

    public int getId() {

        return id;

    }

    public void setId(int id) {

        this.id = id;

    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;

    }

}
```

Sender class

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;

import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;

import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;

import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;

import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;



import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Properties;



import vo.User;



public class Sender {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        User user = new User(10,"testName");

        Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(user.getClass());

        GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);



        //working fine

        /*avroRecord.put("id", user.getId());

        avroRecord.put("name", user.getName());*/



        //not working

        DatumWriter<Object> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<Object>(schema);

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);

        try {

            datumWriter.write(user, encoder);

            encoder.flush();

        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();

        }



        ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record = new ProducerRecord<>("avrotesttopic1",avroRecord);



        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");

        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);

        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);

        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");



        KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord>(props);



        try {

            producer.send(record);

            producer.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }



        producer.close();

    }

}
```

How can i publish this object to my Kafka topic as Avro?

I have referred the below links

https://github.com/akmalmuqeeth/confluent-kafka-spring-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/ConfluentProducerApp.java

https://findusages.com/search/org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter/write$2?offset=23

https://www.ctheu.com/2017/03/02/serializing-data-efficiently-with-apache-avro-and-dealing-with-a-schema-registry/

Thank you.

Comment: You mention in the comments that you are using Reflect Avro, but you are not... You should really add your Avro model separated, as shown here. https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.3.0-post/kafka-clients/specific-avro-producer

Comment: if that is the case the question is different. I will update my answer to guide you on that part

Answer (score 2):

it is possible to accomplish what you are trying using `ReflectDatumWriter`, the only restriction is that to read the data you will need `ReflectDatumReader` which will expect and empty constructor as part of your class. The following code is working (without kafka, at least serialize/deserialize)

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        User user = new User(10, "testName");
        Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(user.getClass());
        GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);

        ReflectDatumWriter<User> datumWriter = new ReflectDatumWriter<User>(schema);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);
        datumWriter.write(user,  encoder);
        encoder.flush();

        ReflectDatumReader<Object> reader = new ReflectDatumReader<Object>(schema);
        User after =  (User)reader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(outputStream.toByteArray(), null));
        System.out.println(after.getId());
        System.out.println(after.getName());
    }

    public static class User {
        int id;
        String name;

        public User(){

        }

        public User(int id, String name) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

I would recommend for sure use schema registry together with AvroSerializer/AvroDeserializer or in the worst case use schema based compiled classes to ensure compatibility at topic level in Kafka and sure perform much better than the reflective solution.

EDIT:

If you want to use `KafkaAvroSerializer`/`KafkaAvroDeserializer` you must provide a supported object for serialization (you can find the list [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java#L109)). As you can see, it is expecting a primitive type or an `IndexedRecord`, what it means is essentially that you need to provide a compiled avro class or a `GenericRecord` to be serialized/deserialized, there is no way to work directly with your POJO object with the KafkaAvro SerDe implementation.

The other option is implement your own serializer/deserializar to handle the byte array serialized/serialized in my example.

Comment: hi @hlagos thanks for your help. I am using schema registry already. In the code u have provided, the `send` part is missing (it is there in my code). Could you kindly post the full code?

Comment: if that is the case the question is different. I will update my answer to guide you on that part

Answer (score -2):

You should create avro schema first and generate your Java class from that schema with `avro-tools` or `avro-maven-plugin`. Working example can be found [here](https://jvzoggel.com/2016/10/19/publishing-apache-avro-messages-on-a-apache-kafka-topic/)

Comment: Hi, the serializer i want is confluent avro serializer, not ByteArraySerializer.

Comment: It's ok, you can use serializer by confluent,  the steps are the same. 1. Create .avsc file 2. Generate java class 3. Create java object and send it to Kafka.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me why i need avsc file? I am generating schema from the object using reflect. Again, java classes and object, I have the User object already, which I want to send.

Comment: If you do not provide special conversion, GenericDatumWriter expects the type of the object to be `org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord`. 
When you have generated class it will extend `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase` and implement `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord`. So you will just call
`User u = new User();
 producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, u);`

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ This answer is saying `User` will be **generated from** the avsc (though, I prefer avdl).

Comment: @cricket_007 could you post avdl code as an answer?

Comment: Your link doesn't use the Confluent Schema Registry. While the plugin will still work, the Avro needs to be sent differently